# 3D-animated kids' show about a man who wants to become a knight but has a magical part of a sword

Tags: story-identification, tv, magic, animated-series

I remember when I was young, there was a 3D-animated TV show. It was around 2010-2015 I believe.

In it, a man really wanted to become a knight but he never passed. I believe he lived up on a floating island in a house, but then one knight's sword broke and he used a part of that sword to do things like create a shield. The bad guy was up in a floating ship.